# block size logic with Bootstrap container is strange

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I have this problem with two blocks in bootstrap

[image: http://s2.micp.ru/1XX3u.png]

Why **footer (#2)** have `400px height`?

If I remove **top block (#1)** - `footer height = 0px` **(works correctly)**; If I set `overflow:hidden (to #1 block)` - works correctly! But why without `overflow - footer` **height is big**?

**Demo:**

```css
.footer{
  background-color: #f60;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="new_search" style="height: 100px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12" style="height: 500px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container footer">
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats

*A floating image obscures borders of block boxes it overlaps.*

[image: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/images/float2p.png]

First **div (#1)** has `height:100px;` but content `(.col-xs-12)` have `float: left; height: 500px;`

`float: left;` create a "flying box" with `height:500px`

[image]

```css
div{
  margin: 1px;
}
#div1{
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
#div2{
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

If I create a sipmle **new div #2** (default `clear: none;`) - The block is placed on top (because `clear: none;`)

[image]

```css
div{
  margin: 1px;
}
#div1{
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
#div2{
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  float: left;
}
#div3{
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
<div id="div3"></div>
```

But if I add a new **block #3** with `clear: both;` into div - block is placed to bottom, because `clear: both;` push down from "flying box"

[image]

```css
div{
  margin: 1px;
}
#div1{
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
#div2{
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  float: left;
}
#div3{
  border: 3px solid red;
}
#div4{
  clear: both;
  border: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
<div id="div3">
  <div id="div4"></div>
</div>
```

Therefore footer height generated from the end of the div #1 (red block) to end of child (block #3) position

[image]

I apologize for my bad English :)

Answer (score 0):

Float is the problem , if you remove float from col-xs-12 or you set float:left;  to footer it works like you want . Hope it helps .

You should have a clearfix container holding the float div.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of *why* this happens. The clearfix method is the cause, definitely, but it doesn't explain why the `.footer` element inherits the height of the `.col-xs-12` element.

Comment: And it's not the answer, it has to do with float, but it also has to do with the footer having a container class (before and after). Removing that and just setting the width to 100% also "fixes" the problem

Comment: I know a lot of options for solutions. But the main question - why is this happening?

Comment: Footer is div , its display is block by default so it takes the remain height of its parent container 500px - 100px = 400px .

Comment: display: block == width 100%, but default height is 0px, But in this situation, its height is not 0, why?

Comment: if you see bootstrap :before and :after pseudoelements ::before is table and ::after is clearfix so they take remaining height also.

Answer (score 0):

Well interesting problem,

It's the "before and after" elements of the footer classes *"container"* and *"row"* are causing this problem.

It's because the **:before** thinks that the element before only were 100 px in height.

But the **:after** calculated the visual height to 500 px since we don't use *"overflow:hidden"*.

Since bootstap makes a "*display: table*" between these two poins the footer gets a height of 400px.

This code would shows that the pseudo **:after** element forces a block is the problem:

```
.footer{
  background-color: #f60;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100px;

}
.container.footer .row:after, .container.footer:after{
  display: inline !important;
  content: " ";
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://www.bootply.com/pmt7X56qHw